# Using React in not-react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twig

I have a project where all the views renders by the server using `Twig` template engine. So I write all my scripts inside the `.twig` templates.

For example, this is my `aside-buttons.twig` template:

```
  <div class="aside-buttons">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Twiter</a>
    <a href="#">FB</a>
    <a href="#">Youtube</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.each($('.aside-buttons a'), function() {
        this.onclick = function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(this.text);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Is there any possibility to use `React` to create for example this simple 
 `aside-buttons` template and make it work in another `.twig` template file? Thank you in advance!

PS: I used `React` in projects where entire `client` part was created using `React`, and I noticed that writing complex `client` components in `React` is very handy.

Comment: You can export your template and logic as React components but you would have to rely on React.DOM to render those components in a part of your intended HTML spot.

Comment: @Rikin, `export your template and logic as React components` I'm not quite understand how can I do this...

Comment: One thing I like about Vue.JS is that you can adopt it incrementally, just on the webparts you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here's something that should do what you want to do.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("aside-buttons");

const clickHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
};

const Buttons = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>Home</button>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>Twitter</button>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>FB</button>
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>YouTube</button>
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Buttons />, el);

/* You can also use this if you don't want to compile JSX

const Buttons = () => React.createElement(
  React.Fragment,
  null,
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    { onClick: clickHandler },
    "Home"
  ),
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    { onClick: clickHandler },
    "Twitter"
  ),
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    { onClick: clickHandler },
    "FB"
  ),
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    { onClick: clickHandler },
    "YouTube"
  )
);

*/
```

And your template should just have this:

`<div id="aside-buttons"></div>`